# TextBox SetFocus not working after handling error and MsgBox VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a userform using VBA in Excel and found a very specific issue. `txtPymt` is a textbox that is never supposed to be empty. In order to prevent that I coded this:

```
Private Sub txtPymt_AfterUpdate()

  'Prevent empty textbox
  On Error Resume Next
  txtPymt = txtPymt.Value + 0
  If Err.Number = 13 Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid value"
    txtPymt = Format(0, "Standard")
    txtPymt.SetFocus
    Err.Clear
    
  Else
    'Format entry
    txtPymt = Format(txtPymt.Value, "Standard")
    
  End If

End Sub
```

This way I can be sure that the textbox only accepts numeric values (otherwise the code would jump to the error code) and avoid the `IsEmpty` vulnerability to blank spaces. After an invalid entry the value of the textbox is successfully changed back to 0. But, I would also like to `SetFocus` to that same textbox after clicking `Ok` in the `MsgBox`. Even though I put that in my code, I can't `SetFocus` to the same textbox. In fact, the function doesn't work with any other textbox.

I also tried setting focus to another textbox first and then to `txtPymt`, and using the `Exit` event instead of `AfterUpdate` but I had no success. The message box pops up when pressing TAB or clicking another text field. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub txtPymt_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    txtPymt = txtPymt.Value + 0
    If Err.Number = 13 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid value"
        Cancel = True
        Err.Clear
    Else
        'Format entry
        txtPymt = Format(txtPymt.Value, "Standard")
    End If
End Sub
```